# Specifying multiple -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio and -webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio css media queries

Tags: css, html, mobile, media-queries

Need ability to specify different css for different device-pixel-ratio values. How can this be done

For example,

> ```
> 0 <= range 1 <= 1
> 1 <  range 2 <= 1.5
> 1.5 <  range 3 <= 2.0
> 2.0 < range 4
> ```

Example media query looks like

> ```
> >     @media (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:1.0) {
> >         .fontCls {
> >             color: #FF00FF; // pink
> >             font-size: 20px;
> >             text-decoration: overline;
> >         }
> >     }
> >     
> >     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.0) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:1.4) {
> >         .fontCls {
> >             color: #FF00FF; // pink
> >             font-size: 16px;
> >             text-decoration: line-through;
> >         }
> >     }
> >     
> >     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:1.9) {
> >         .fontCls {
> >             color: #FF00FF; // pink
> >             font-size: 16px;
> >             text-decoration: underline;
> >         }
> >     }
> >     
> >     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2.0) {
> >         .fontCls {
> >            color: #FF00FF; // pink
> >             font-size: 16px;
> >             font-weight: bold;
> >         }
> >     }
> ```

Comment: Your code is exactly how you would do it. Is something wrong or not working with your code. It appears to be structured correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the link tag as shown below. Change the href to the correct path of your target specific CSS

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='ss1.css' media='only screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1)'/>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='ss2.css' media='only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.4)'/>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='ss3.css' media='only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.9)'/>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='ss4.css' media='only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)'/>
```